# sum of array using multithreading

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading

I implement sum element of array using multi threading but my question is when my program work with one thread the time is better than using 6 thread . I am using a CPU with 8 threads.What am I wrong

```
public static int threadss = 7;
        public const int count = 1000000;
        public static List<int> a = new List<int>();
        public static int numberofthreads;
        public static long[] sum=new long[threadss];
        public static long total_sum=0;
        public static long part = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
               a.Add(i);

            }

            numberofthreads = threadss;

            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            Thread[] threadsarray = new Thread[numberofthreads];
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
           
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
            {
                threadsarray[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(myThreadMethod));
                threadsarray[i].Start(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
            {
                threadsarray[i].Join();
            }
           for(int i= 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
            {
                total_sum += sum[i];

            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time is " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("sum is "+ total_sum);
        } 
        static void myThreadMethod(object threadid)
        {
            int thid = (int)threadid;
            for (int i = (thid * (a.Count / numberofthreads));i < (thid + 1) * a.Count / numberofthreads; i++)
            {
                sum[thid] += a[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since the sum operation is not a really CPU intense operation that's why most of your application time are spent on thread synchronization. Please use profiling tools like [CodeTrack](https://www.getcodetrack.com/) to better understand how does your code work in case of multi threading.

Comment: I doubt you’re asking about a problem where you actually need to sum an array of numbers fast, but there’s a method, `sum`, to do that. This is an operation you’d normally want to vectorize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running your code in Release build after a tweak like `i < count` instead of `i <= count` and increased array size by 10 times, and assign 1 for each array element (needed for further comparison):

```
Time is 177
sum is 10000000
```

Then I've made some changes

```cs
public const int numberofthreads = 7;
public const int count = 10000000;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 1;
    }

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    long sum1 = ThreadSum(a);

    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time is " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("sum is " + sum1);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static long ThreadSum(int[] array)
{
    long total_sum = 0;
    long[] sum = new long[numberofthreads];
    Thread[] threadsarray = new Thread[numberofthreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
    {
        int tmp = i;
        threadsarray[i] = new Thread(() => MyThreadMethod(tmp, array, sum));
        threadsarray[i].Start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
    {
        threadsarray[i].Join();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
    {
        total_sum += sum[i];
    }
    return total_sum;
}

static void MyThreadMethod(int threadid, int[] array, long[] sum)
{
    int thid = threadid;
    for (int i = thid * (array.Length / numberofthreads); i < (thid + 1) * array.Length / numberofthreads; i++)
    {
        sum[thid] += array[i];
    }
}
```

```
Time is 6
sum is 10000000
```

Interesting. That's mostly faster because I'm using `Array` instead of `List` for the source data. Let's make some more optimisations like using pooled threads.

```
static long ThreadSum(int[] array)
{
    long total_sum = 0;
    long[] sum = new long[numberofthreads];
    Task[] tasks = new Task[numberofthreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
    {
        int tmp = i;
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => MyThreadMethod(tmp, array, sum));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
    {
        total_sum += sum[i];
    }
    return total_sum;
}
```

No progress

```
Time is 6
sum is 10000000
```

...because internal threading overhead here is the same. But in wide thread use i recommend `Task.Run` instead of `new Thread`.

Ok, let's do that in the old way

```cs
static long Sum(int[] array)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```
Time is 5
sum is 10000000
```

One thread is almost faster than 7 threads. :) That's because of the same threading overhead. Creating thread is expensive operation.

But what about SIMD?

```
static long SimdSum(int[] array)
{
    Vector<int> sumVector = Vector<int>.Zero;
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector<int>> vectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, Vector<int>>(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
    {
        sumVector += vectors[i];
    }
    long sum = Vector.Dot(sumVector, Vector<int>.One);
    for (int i = array.Length - array.Length % Vector<int>.Count; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My `Vector<int>` length is 8, then it works like 8 threads but on one thread because SIMD instruction calculates 8 `int`s at once.

```
Time is 2
sum is 10000000
```

Looks like it the fastest for now. Probably there's more ways to optimize that but I think, that's enough. The main issue that threading here isn't effective because computation time for the each Thread is too small.

Also, I suggest to say hello to **Benchmark.NET**, it can measure methods performance more accurately.

Answer (score 3):

The computations you are doing are absolutely trivial. Summing integers is pretty much one of the fastest operations a CPU can do.

In particular, the computation is *much* faster than the time it takes to even spin up a *single* thread, let alone spin up six of them – and that's not even talking about merging back the results and destroying the threads.

The overhead for parallelism absolutely dwarfs the computation in your case.